# inotify stops reporting events

Tags: linux, c, inotify

I am using `inotify` in a program written in `C`; it closely follows the example in `man 7 inotify`.  The steps are essentially:

```
/* setup */
int fd = inotify_init1(IN_NONBLOCK);
int wd = inotify_add_watch(fd, path, IN_CLOSE_WRITE);
struct pollfd fds[1];
fds[0].fd = fd;
fds[0].events = POLLIN;

/* within main loop */
int poll_num = poll(fds, 1, 0);
if (poll_num == -1) { /* error handling */ }
else if (poll_num>0) {
    if (fds[0].revents & POLLERR ||
        fds[0].revents & POLLHUP ||
        fds[0].revents & POLLNVAL) { /* error handling */ }
    if (fds[0].revents & POLLIN) { /* read events */ }
}
```

While reading events, the event mask is checked for queue overflow (`IN_Q_OVERFLOW`), filesystem unmounting (`IN_UNMOUNT`), and other problems (`IN_IGNORED`).  None of these conditions (nor `POLLERR`, `POLLHUP`, etc.) ever occur.

This works well for a while (usually for run times of a day or two).  Then, for no apparent reason, `inotify` stops reporting events.  The rest of my program continues to run without any problems, but it no longer receives any events from `inotify.`  I'm not sure how to debug this, since I believe I am checking all the relevant error conditions.  The watched file is still  in place and has the same inode as it had when `inotify` was set up to monitor it.

What would cause `inotify` to stop reporting events without generating any errors in a program?

Comment: Have you verified that the file hasn’t been ``logrotate``’d?

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica': Yes, the file is not subject to `logrotate`, but thanks for the suggestion.